# Android Firebase: does SMS code have to be sent everytime user signs in?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hi I am integrating Phone number authentication in my android app using firebase and I am successfully done with the sign up part by having the user enter his phone number and the phone number gets verified by SMS code sent to that entered phone number and after the user types this code in, the user is signed in, redirected to his account activity and has an entry created for him in Firebase console.

The problem is when I sign the user out using the following code:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();.
```

and sign back in, I get a new sms code.
Does the user have to get a new sms code and go through the same process once again ?
isn't that bad for limited quota ? (10k/month free plan)

Comment: You should only call sign out when the user explicitly requests it. For most users that is quite uncommon.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen That is a potential spam case. I mean if users keep signing out and in, the quota limit will be reached in no time.

Comment: If you suspect your users are abusing your system, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.